# OnSave event on a custom entity form in CRM 2015 enters in a recursive trigger

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

I have an event registered onSave on form of a custom entity on a crm 2015 on premise organization, which seems to enter in a recursive call. After i hit save the event keeps call it self, until i kill IE through task manager or the IE crashes with memory stack full. I have checked and it doesn't seem to be related to what i have in the function, meaning i am not triggering in any way the on save event again.

Here is the function code:

```
function contract_OnSave(context) {

    var eventArgs = context.getEventArgs();
    if (eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 1) {

        if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_field").getValue() != null) {
            var mort = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_field").getValue();

            if (mort == true) {


                Xrm.Utility.confirmDialog("Would you like to open a new window for a Case?",
                    saveFormOnOpenCase,
                    callback)
            }
        }
    }
}
function saveFormOnOpenCase()
{
    Xrm.Page.data.save();
    var parameters = {};
    parameters["new_subjectnew"] = 100000002;
    // Open the window.
    var windowOptions = {
        openInNewWindow: true
    };
    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", null, parameters, windowOptions);
}
function callback() {

}
```

It seemed to me like it is a bug in CRM 2015, after which i checked the version of the CRM, and noticed it is the RTM version. I suggested a CRM upgrade to Update 1 and it seemed as the most logical step to take. But even after the upgrade, the issue is still there.

I tried registering the same function on OnChange event on the field, and it was working fine, except the openInNewWindow option, of the openEntityForm function, which does not open a new window, but that is a different issue.

I am using IE 11.

Can someone please confirm if this is happening in another CRM 2015 environment as well, or if i am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem which makes the OnSave function go into a recursive call is in the following:

```
var windowOptions = {
    openInNewWindow: true
};    
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", null, parameters, windowOptions);
```

As mentioned in the link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx.

The windowOptions parameter in the openEntityForm should open the new form in a new window but for some reason it doesn't, although the CRM is updated with update 1 for CRM 2015. Because the form doesn't open in a new window, when leaving the current form, an auto-save event is fired which causes the form to enter the recursion and initiate the OnSave event.

I fixed the issue by using pure a javascript function (not using the CRM SDK) to open the form in a new window, which doesn't initiate the OnSave event.

Answer (score 1):

In the OnSave event you ask the user for confirmation:

```
Xrm.Utility.confirmDialog("Would you like to open a new window for a Case?",
                saveFormOnOpenCase,
                callback)
```

When the user selects OK, this dialog executes function `saveFormOnOpenCase`. The first instruction this function executes is:

```
Xrm.Page.data.save();
```

... triggering the save event again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it has given me a clue. I'd forgotten to remove that Xrm.Page.data.save(); save form line, which i put after i put the event on change of the field. I will check again.

Comment: The actual problem is that, 

Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", null, parameters, windowOptions);

opens the case record form in the same window, instead of a new one, as noted in MSDN online, 

which actually, i believe, triggers the auto-save on the form, which causes the recursion on the event.So i will need to use pure JavaScript code to open the new window, instead of the sdk code (which does not work as intended), or prevent the default event if i can...